# Iterating through a beautiful soup array in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just started learning webscraping in python using beautiful soup. I'm trying to access a certain value in an array given from find_all(). I can print out all of the array easily, but I'm having trouble just printing out one element of it. When I loop through it, it's all stored in the 0th element, and any value greater than 0 will result in an index out of range exception.

The loop works fine and shows that i is 0 through every iteration. the print above it that tries to access an element doesn't work and I need help trying to access one of the td's returned by the find_all. If there isn't a way to do it, then I guess I need help refining my search to the game mode and rank. 
Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#python -m pip install lxml
result  = requests.get("https://rocketleague.tracker.network/profile/steam/teicho")

src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find(id = "season-13")
rank = links.find_all('tr')
bound = len(rank)

data = []
for i in range(bound):
  print("")
  tds = [rank[i].find_all('td')]
  print(tds[1]) #where the error occurs
  for i in range(0,len(tds)):
    print (i)
    print(tds[i])
    print("")
```

Here's part of the output from the loop that shows what's in tds, because if i post the whole thing I can't get past stack overflow's spam filter:

```
0
[]


0[<td style="width:32px;"><img src="/Images/RL/ranked/s4-4.png" style="width:30px;"/></td>, <td>Reward Level<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Silver</small>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
0
<div class="season-rank">
(Top 40%)
</div>
</td>]


0
[]


0
[<td style="width:32px;">
<img src="/Images/RL/ranked/s4-0.png" style="width:30px;"/>
<td>
Un-Ranked
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Unranked
Division I
</small>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
2,190
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 1%)</span>
</div>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
n/a
</td>
</td>, <td>
Un-Ranked
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Unranked
Division I
</small>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
2,190
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 1%)</span>
</div>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
n/a
</td>]


0
[<td style="width:32px;">
<img src="/Images/RL/ranked/s4-13.png" style="width:30px;"/>
<td>
Ranked Duel 1v1
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Diamond I
Division III
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="trnToolTips.showHelp('Estimated Tier/Division', 'Since you have not played Rocket League recently, Psyonix has removed your Tier and Division.  You are currently unranked.  We have tried to estimate whatyour tier/division should be, if you still played. That iswhat we are showing here!');">
<i class="ion ion-alert-circled" style="color:red; font-size: 12px;"></i>
</a>
</small>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
846
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 8%)</span>
</div>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
4
</td>
</td>, <td>
Ranked Duel 1v1
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Diamond I
Division III
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="trnToolTips.showHelp('Estimated Tier/Division', 'Since you have not played Rocket League recently, Psyonix has removed your Tier and Division.  You are currently unranked.  We have tried to estimate whatyour tier/division should be, if you still played. That iswhat we are showing here!');">
<i class="ion ion-alert-circled" style="color:red; font-size: 12px;"></i>
</a>
</small>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
846
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 8%)</span>
</div>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
4
</td>]


0
[<td style="width:32px;">
<img src="/Images/RL/ranked/s4-17.png" style="width:30px;"/>
<td>
Ranked Doubles 2v2
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Champion II
Division I
</small>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:red;">~8</span>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
1,303
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 7%)</span>
</div>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:green;">~9</span>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
31
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Win Streak: 2
</small>
</td>
</td>, <td>
Ranked Doubles 2v2
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Champion II
Division I
</small>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:red;">~8</span>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
1,303
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 7%)</span>
</div>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:green;">~9</span>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
31
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Win Streak: 2
</small>
</td>]


0
[<td style="width:32px;">
<img src="/Images/RL/ranked/s4-0.png" style="width:30px;"/>
<td>
Ranked Solo Standard 3v3
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Unranked
Division I
</small>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
892
<div class="season-rank">
(Top 10%)
</div>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
0
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Losing Streak: 9
</small>
</td>
</td>, <td>
Ranked Solo Standard 3v3
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Unranked
Division I
</small>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
892
<div class="season-rank">
(Top 10%)
</div>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
0
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Losing Streak: 9
</small>
</td>]


0
[<td style="width:32px;">
<img src="/Images/RL/ranked/s4-16.png" style="width:30px;"/>
<td>
Ranked Standard 3v3
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Champion I
Division III
</small>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:red;">~20</span>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
1,257
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 9%)</span>
</div>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:green;">~10</span>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">
10
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Win Streak: 2
</small>
</td>
</td>, <td>
Ranked Standard 3v3
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Champion I
Division III
</small>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:red;">~20</span>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
1,257
<div class="season-rank">
<span class="text text-success"> (Top 9%)</span>
</div>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
<span style="color:green;">~10</span>
</td>, <td style="text-align:center;">
10
<small style="display:block; font-size:10px; color:gray">
Win Streak: 2
</small>
</td>]
```

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: when i go to print (tds[1]) I get a list index out of range error

Comment: what do you get when you print `len(tds)`

Comment: I get 12 when I print out the length

Comment: what is the length when you get the error

Answer (score 0):

`tds[1]` will always be wrong because on the line before, you put the returned list into another list, by adding the block parentheses around the function.

```
tds = [rank[i].find_all('td')] # Wrong
tds = rank[i].find_all('td') # Correct
```

Comment: I removed the brackets and got the same list index out of range error :(

Answer (score 0):

I traversed through the source code differently and put all of it into a list. I had to strip a bunch of \n's that were in the source code for some reason. But it's how the people made their website. Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#python -m pip install lxml
result  = requests.get("https://rocketleague.tracker.network/profile/steam/teicho")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
tbl = soup.find(id = "season-13")
rank = tbl.find_all("table", class_ = "card-table items")

ranks = [rank[1].find("tbody").text]
for i in range(len(ranks)):
  print(ranks[i].replace('\n',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

The range error is because you are using the variable `i` twice in the `for` loops, try using `j` or any other variable

Comment: While using the same iteration variable in nested loops *is* a BAD Idea, I don't think there's a connection to the run time error reported.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30814841)